# Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm new into C# and I'm getting the error as title said. I know it's a duplicate my question, but others questions found with the same title, didn't helped me much so, I'm asking you polite to be kind.

I'm using the following code in order to populare a combo from a MSSQL database:

```
        public void popmarca()
    {
        string select = "SELECT DISTINCT ta.Marca  from TipAutocar ta INNER JOIN Autocare a ON ta.idtipautocar=a.idtipautocar";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (select, con);
               DataSet ds = new DataSet();
               DataTable dt = new DataTable("marci");
               SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               dt.Load(sdr);
               ds.Tables.Add(dt);
               cmbMarca.DataSource = ds.Tables["marci"];
               cmbMarca.DisplayMember="Marca";
               cmbMarca.ValueMember="IDTipAutocar";
               cmbMarca.Refresh();
               con.Close();



            }
        }
        catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
    }
```

Please, if anyone is willing to help me find out what am I missing.. Thanks!

Comment: `cmbMarca.DataBind()` basically it's telling you that you have not called the DataBind() method from what it looks like.. also look up how to use the `Fill()` Method instead..

Comment: There is no `IDTipAutocar` in the select statement

Comment: @MikeDebela - you are right. I did that and it worked. But now the problem is, in my sql table, I have the same name (eg: Mercedes) multiple times and now the select it doesn't take count by `DISTINCT` condition in the `SELECT` condition. Ideas?

Comment: That's a different problem an requires a different question.  The reason you are getting the error here is that your SQL statement doesn't output the column referenced in the `ValueMember` field. (Which @MikeDebela should put down as an answer :))

Comment: @MikeC - I totally agree :)). But still, any ideas? :D

Comment: @rrrrdc Again `That's a different problem and requires a different question.`!!!!